# Wrap a database stored image inside an Ext.Img component

Tags: extjs, extjs4

So I have some images stored in my database. They are kept as BLOBs, not as a path to the physical location. I can access them via: `http://example.com/data/pageMedia?id=%someId%`.

But when I want to wrap the image in Ext.Img:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
    src: 'http://example.com/data/pageMedia?id=' + someId,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

it doesn't render the image.

It works fine with pure HTML, though:

```html
<img src="http://example.com/data/pageMedia?id=%someId%"/>
```

Should I use an Ajax request or something else and set `src` dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.Img',{
      src : 'Gallery/GetImage/' + imageId,
      renderTo: 'cat-img' // in your case Ext.getBody()
 });
```

Notice how I create my image URL. If you someId is a js variable and not hardcoded, you will have to write:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Img',{
    src : 'http://mysite.com/data/pageMedia?id='+someId,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: I guess I didn't make my self clear, sorry! in place of someId i put a number like this :

      src : 'http://mysite.com/data/pageMedia?id=337'

but still not working!

Comment: do you get any error? check if your browser is requesting for the image and what server is sending..

Comment: no errors! the server is sending the image! but when i'm trying to work with the 'Ext.Img' i've created, it says that it's not defined!